# Automization of ACLS creation in kafka

Tags: security, apache-kafka, authorization

I want to automate ACLS creation for the topics in my kafka cluster

I need a solution in a way such that if we want to add a new ACL we just need to update in a file so that it automatically picks it up and create the ACL for the respective user with respective access.

Comment: What research have you done? Asking for tools and libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow. Refer [help]

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer Just want to know if there any tools which maybe helpful. I did some research and found out that kafka-gitops is one of the way of automization of topic creation and ACL creations. Just want to know the if there are any other possible ways of doing this.

Comment: Yes, there are tools, such as the one you found, perhaps. What errors are you having using it?